# Upgrading a Xen host from debian lenny to squeeze

Tags: debian, xen

I am in the process of upgrading the Xen host from Lenny to Squeeze. 
What is the recommended route for this upgrade?

Upgrade the host first then the guests? Will the guests be able to boot if I do this?

If I upgrade the guests using [these](http://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) instructions I wont be able to load the guest after the first restart recommendation right after installing udev and the new linux-image, since the new kernel can't run on a Lenny host (correct this if am wrong).

Some recommendation from someone who has done this would be great

Comment: I don't want to offend, but isn't Xen deprecating at all? What's with the vital and flexible, easy to use (compared to Xen) alternative, the KVM/Qemu Module? Works really well and stable here on lenny for years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I never got an answer but I bit the bullet and went with my instincts. Here is what I did in case anyone might find this useful.

First of all remember the host(dom0) boots the guests(domU) using the kernels stored in the host. So the process:

1. `apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade`
2. `apt-get install udev`
3. `shutdown` the guest (yes not reboot)

Then moving on to the host - I followed [these](http://mrngm.com/xen-on-debian-lenny-to-squeeze.html) instructions which are just a concise version of the longer xen upgrade page [here](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen).

With the host fully upgraded, it's time to fully upgrade the guests.

Edit the `kernel` and `ramdisk` parameters in `/etx/xen/yourguest.cfg` so that it matches whatever your host is running. In my case changed for example

`kernel='/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64`' to

`kernel='/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64`' (change `ramdisk` to the appropriate value)

I then used `xm create` to boot the guests, which loaded without a hitch. Then proceeded to `apt-get dist-upgrade` each guest in turn and voila! It's an all squeeze affair now.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded a few of my Xen guests to squeeze this weekend.

No, you can't install a `linux-image` package on a guest, just `linux-modules`. But upgrading `linux-modules` on a guest will require upgrading `linux-image` on the host. When I do the host's squeeze upgrade, I'll install the new modules on all the squeeze guests. Installing `udev` during section 4.4.5 is fine, though.

Short form, I just installed `udev` in section 4.4.5, and left the kernel alone. The rest of the upgrade guide is accurate.